# Page for each Taxonomy term in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

Apologies for being a total idiot as I'm a novice at drupal. I have created a Vocabulary named "Brands" and inside it I have a taxonomy tree like so

- brand1

  - cateogry1

    - product1
  - category2
- brand2

  - category1
  - category2

    - product1
    - product2

I want to create a separate menu for this taxonomy and using "Taxonomy Menu" module I have done it. But what I need is a page listing all the terms inside a parent term. Like when brand1 is clicked a page loads that lists the categories inside it and the same happens for products inside categories as well. This doesn't happen by default. When a parent link is clicked an empty page shows up. So how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked much with the taxonomy menu module, but your 'listing of terms' need sounds like a good candidate for a view!

Have you used the 'views' module yet?  http://drupal.org/project/views

Here are some video tutorials that can get you started with views: http://drupal.org/node/1351076

Comment: Views has a built-in "Taxonomy term" view (though disabled by default) which you can look at as an example.